# Averaging value around the histogram peak using std::map

Tags: c++, iterator

I am trying to average the keys around the histogram peak. So, I first find the peak and then my attempt was to add one and subtract one from the peak index to find the average key around the peak. I find the index using the distance function. However, I am unable to find the right solution, because the code wont compile. Can anyone please help?

```
int iterator_distance;

for ( std::map<float, int>::iterator it = histogram_x.begin(); it != histogram_x.end(); it++) {
    if (max_occurence.x <= it->second ) {
        max_occurence.x = it->second;
        max_voted.x = it->first;
        iterator_distance = std::distance(histogram_x.begin(), it);
        //std::cout << x.first << " histogram " << x.second << "endx\n";
    }
}
// Average around the peak

if ( iterator_distance > 2 ) {
    max_voted.x = (histogram_x.begin()+iterator_distance-1)->first + (histogram_x.begin()+iterator_distance)->first + (histogram_x.begin()+iterator_distance+1)->first;
}
```

The following is the error . The error says that the plus operator cannot be used with iterators and float. But thats my question, how can I solve this problem?

```
error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::map<float, int>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const float, int> >}’ and ‘int’)
                 max_voted.x = (histogram_x.begin()+iterator_distance)->first +  (histogram_x.begin()+iterator_distance-1)->first;
```

Comment: cmon people... alteast tell why are you downvoting. If you dont, then its difficult to know what is wrong in my post

Comment: "code wont compile" is not an appropriate error description!

Comment: got it. updated the post.

Comment: `std::map::iterator` is a `BidirectionalIterator`, which you can increment and decrement, but you cannot add values to it with `+`.

Comment: @DanielLangr thats what I read too, but then how can I average the peak of the histogram?

Comment: An idea: While looping over map to find the peak, you could remember the predecessor and successor values as well. Don't forget border cases (e.g. to handle peak at first or last element) respectively.

Comment: @infoclogged Why don't you just remember the iterator for the peak? Then, you can increment and decrement it to find neighbor elements.

Comment: @DanielLangr - let me try.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in C++11:

```
assert(histogram_x.size() > 0);
auto peak_it = std::max_element(histogram_x.cbegin(), histogram_x.cend(),
   [](const pair<float, int>& lhs, const pair<float, int>& rhs) {
      reutrn lhs.second < rhs.second; });

max_voted.x = peak_it->first;    
if ((peak_it != histogram_x.begin()) && (peak_it != std::prev(histogram_x.end())) 
   max_voted.x += std::prev(peak_it)->first + std::next(peak_it)->first /* / 3.0f ??? */;
```

Comment: awesome ! I already worked on your hint and it worked. But this solution looks so much compact especially with std::prev. I will try this too and get back.